# Discord bot with pre-defined tags

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem. I have a list of programming languages, for example

```
Python
Javascript
Pearl
Dart
C#
C++
Java
```

The user should be assigned a maximum of three programming languages as roles. Is there a possibility to use a tag input like for web pages in Discord?
For example, the user just writes `Ja` and the user gets back `Java` and `JavaScript` and can select them. See photo.

[image]

Is there a way to do something like this in Discord as a bot?

---

I have seen that some bots have such a tag. However, I don't know if it is freely definable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Select Rows.[image: Example of select row]

Resources:

- [Discord Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#select-menus)
- [Discord.py Select Menus](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#select-menus)
- [Discord.py Role Select Menus](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#roleselect)

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please provide a MVC?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what a MVC refers to. Do you mean an example? If so, you can find one [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/dropdown.py)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for. Is also there an option to get this work on mobile ?

Comment: @Test It should work on mobile, as long as they have the updated discord client.